# Matching tunneling packet in OVS

Tags: sdn, tunneling, ryu

I’m working with tunneling traffic (GENEVE and Vxlan). I have some VMs connect with a OVS bridge. Traffic from VMs is both tunnel and non-tunnel. Beside that, I have a Ryu controller to config qos for ports in bridge. I want matching only tunnel traffic in OVS by flow. I know that OVS has metadata fields like: tun_id, tun_src, tun_dst,… for tunnel traffic, but that fields is only for tunnel port. I tried set ports which connect with VMs to tunnel port with remote_ip is flow. But by that way, Ryu controller can’t find and config this port.

So i want to ask: Does have any way to OVS matching tunnel traffic in non-tunnel port or have any way to Ryu controller can find and config to tunnel port?